# Retrieving Values From Excel Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Im trying to retrieve a specific value from each sheet in excel.
The code works fine for a test excel workbook but does not work with the excel file im trying to retrieve.

The error encountered is,

```
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Specified named range 'Table156723451819202122232434567891011121314151619216710111213162024254567101718193456781112131623242528234789101314151619202128910111215234567891011121314161718192021222324252627282930312345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293032234567891011140' does not exist in the current workbook."
```

The target excel book only has 1 month of sheets.(1jan,2jan...)
And the cell im targeting looks like this:

[image]

The target cell formula as follows: =SUM(D23:D24)

The following are my codes:

```
for(int i=0; i<=30; i++){
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("D25"); 
            //CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("A4"); 
            Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
            Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol()); 

            //System.out.println("i:"+row.getCell(cellReference.getCol()));
            //CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
            CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);

            switch (cellValue.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.println(cellValue.getBooleanValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.println(cellValue.getNumberValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.println(cellValue.getStringValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                    break;

                // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never happen
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
                    break;
            }
```

I had tried to put the same formula in my test excel which works fine.
Do give any guidance for this as im stuck at this for very long. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Using **.XLS format instead of .XLSX** solved this problem.

Cheers! Happy Coding.